# Programmatically disable FilteredTextBoxExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm I'm trying to disable all `FilteredTextBoxExtender` in a routine that can be call in the code behind of my application.

So far, I have been able to disable all `TextBox` with this code:

```
protected void DisableControls(Control parent, bool State)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)(c)).Enabled = State;

        DisableControls(c, State);
    }
}
```

But if I try the same with `FilteredTextBoxExtender` is not working. I've tried so far:

```
((FilteredTextBoxExtender)(c)).Enabled = State;

((FilteredTextBoxExtender)(c)).EnableViewState = State;
```

The aspx code (if needed):

```
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="Tip_doc_fil" runat="server"
    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="tip_docu" ValidChars="0123456789">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Comment: Does that work if you manually assign Enabled="False" ?

Comment: @mjw No, I just try manually but is not working either.

Comment: I was asking because the API documentation doesn't show a property for Enabled. You may need to craft a workaround by blanking out the TargetControlID or ValidChars, if allowed.

Comment: Ok, let me try that.. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
((FilteredTextBoxExtender)(c)).Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

If that works then you can always make the textbox look grayed-out using CSS in addition to the above solution.

Comment: Thank your @Jazimov, no need to grayed-out the textbox.

Comment: OK, you don't need to gray-out, but did the above approach give you the readonly functionality you were seeking?

Comment: Yes, works great. Thank you again. (Sorry about the delay, I was working in a different project)

Comment: If it works, an up-vote on the answer is the correct response. That lets others know what worked without having to read through comments. :) Thanks.